# OpenCV GPU ( CUDA ) Template matching and FFT implementation

Tags: opencv, cuda, gpu, fft, matchtemplate

I am using opencv [GPU::matchTemplate()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/image_processing.html#gpu-matchtemplate) on GTX690.

I checked the function internally and found that gpu::matchTemplate() is not using any FFT in the process, while its CPU counterpart does.

My question is, what is the reason behind not using FFT in the GPU?

Answer (score 6):

OpenCV GPU match template implementation uses FFT if template size if bigger than some threshold (https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/gpu/src/match_template.cpp#L147), otherwise it uses brute-force approach,